# VBA code Help Please

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need help. I need to write a VBA code where I need to match an ID number from the answer sheet to each student submission ( open each student submission separate) once that's done I need to grade it and assign a grade. IF IDs match ( student to answer sheet) then it's a point, if they don't it's no point and if the student has a duplicate ID on their submission it's half a point.

When that's done all the duplicates need to get moved to a sheet called Review records sheet and all full point move to the grade sheet. ANy help please as this is what I have and does not run

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Grade As Double
Dim GradePoint As Long
Dim ID As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim FinalGrade As Integer


'Find and Open Reviewed Records File
' user selected a file - do something
userSelectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
If userSelectedFile = False Then
MsgBox "No file Selected."
Else
' user selected a file - do something
MsgBox "File selected: " & userSelectedFile
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(userSelectedFile)
End If

'Find and Open Reviewed Records File
' user selected a file - do something
userSelectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
If userSelectedFile = False Then
MsgBox "No file Selected."
Else
' user selected a file - do something
MsgBox "File selected: " & userSelectedFile
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(userSelectedFile)
End If
   
    For counter = 1 To 1000
    FinalGrade = FinalGrade + 1
    
        If counter > 0 Then
            FinalGrade = FinalGrade + 0.5
            
            Else
            
            If counter <> 0 Then
            FinalGrade = FinalGrade + 0
            
            Else
            
            If counter = 0 Then
            FinalGrade = FinalGrade + 1
            
            Else
            
            End If
   
   
    
 Do
 
 For Each ID In Collection
        If counter > 0 Then
            FinalGrade = FinalGrade + 0.5
        ID = ReviewedRecordsSheet
    Else
    
      
            If counter = 0 Then
            FinalGrade = FinalGrade + 1
        ID = GradeFileSheet
 
Loop Until ID = GradeFile

••••ˇˇˇˇ
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a free scriptwriting service. You will need to show us what research you have done so far & where you are stuck. Include examples of your work so far. See [How do I ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you already have tried something please post it here, otherwise this question is very likely to be closed.

Comment: Will do sorry about that

Comment: Is that better? sorry first time posting

Comment: So where are you stuck? What does the debugger tell you? Are there any error messages when you run it?

Comment: It just does not do anything, I'm not to sure if it is even the right code to begin with, everytime I click that specific command button nothing happens

Comment: We don't debug your entire code for you. Generally, when I debug, I comment out most code and run to see that it is working. then slowly introduce (uncomment) additional code until I find where it is crashing. At that point you may see the error yourself, or come back to the group to ask for help.

Comment: Okay thank you, appreciate it

Comment: Where did you put the code? In the Click event of the command button?

Comment: The title of your posting is not specific. There are lots of VBA related questions and there is nothing that points to your specific problem.

Comment: "Help please" is not required to receive an answer - this is a Q&A site. 
This is the type of title which rather encourages me to stay away. Your code is ugly because there is no strict indention scheme that you use. Using indentions correctly would already show major errors.

Answer (score -1):

I copied your code into Notepad++ to get line numbers.

Use OPTION EXPLICIT at the beginning of the module. There are a lot of variables that you do not declare using DIM. That already may cause errors.
As a beginner do not write code without using OPTION EXPLICIT!

13 MsgBox "No file Selected." '*** indention is lacking!
17 Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(userSelectedFile) '*** You did not declare setwbNEw
31 For counter = 1 To 1000 '*** You should indent the content of the loop, not the loop itself. Where did you terminate the loop? Which statement is missing?!
32 FinalGrade = FinalGrade + 1 'Indent this line and the other inner lines of your loop
34-49 An IF-construction over a couple of lines has to end with END IF. When in doubt, start with complete outer IF constructions and add the inner ones afterwards
55 For Each ID In Collection '*** Where is the indention?

Your are lacking lots of END IF statements!
Print out your code and draw boxes around code parts that belong to an IF/END IF construction.